# Debugging in single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Sometimes, I want to debug and test my rails code in a single file, instead of running a full rails app.

Is there a way to add the rails methods to a single file for debugging?

For example, I wanted to test and play with the `delegate_missing_to` method, but can't without running inside my actual rails app.

For testing ActiveRecord, I can use `require 'active_record'`, which works really well, but I don't have access to other methods.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out bug reporting test cases from rails.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#create-an-executable-test-case

These are basically rails app in a single file.